# rowspan height/width issue for html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using simple HTML with `table` and in chrome I have problem with height but in firefox it is working fine.

Here is the HTML and [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paul_kri_15/zLvw8u5m/1/#)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table {
         font-family: arial, sans-serif;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
         }
         td, th {
         border: 1px solid #dddddd;
         text-align: left;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>HTML Table</h2>
      <table>
         <tbody>                        
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">
                  Hello World                                                                            
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>some</td>
               <td >some</td>
               <td >some</td>
               <td >some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">
                  <b>LOREM</b>
                  <br>IPSUM<br>IP<br> LOREM<br>IP IPSUM<br>IP LORM <br>IP  IPSUM<br>IP LORAM                                                                                                    
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
               <td > some</td>
            </tr>            
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of **chrome** (as you can see it is not align)

[image]

Screenshot of **firefox**(as you can see it is proper align)

[image]

I tried with `height`, width but still it is not working in chrome, can anyone help me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `<td rowspan="3">`and you close the `tr` tag directly after that. That would be only *one* cell in that row which spans 3 rows, which in this context does not make sense.

The cell (`td`) that spans three rows is the first cell in the first row, followed by 13 more cells *in the same row* (that's where your error is). The second and third row each contain 13 cells, since the first cell (spanning three rows) is already defined in the first row/line.

I suppose you want it as follows, that first cell with `rowspan = "3"` being in one row with the first line of "regular cells, and same for the 4th line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>HTML Table</h2>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="even">
        <td rowspan="3">
          Hello World
        </td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
        <td> some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <tr>

          <td rowspan="3">
            <b>LOREM</b>
            <br>IPSUM<br>IP<br> LOREM<br>IP IPSUM<br>IP LORM <br>IP IPSUM<br>IP LORAM
          </td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
          <td> some</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so you mean firefox ignore this kind of things ? as in firefox it looks perfect

Comment: all browsers to some extent are tolerant and try to fix errors by themseleves. In this situation Firefox seems to handle that better than Chrome. But it doesn't "look perfect": You have a rowspan of "3" and only two rows - that can't be perfect, what ever you had in mind...

Comment: BTW: If you intended to have only four rows (2x2), you need to change `rowspan` to `2` and erase the 3rd and 6th row in my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo. I took your code and played a bit with it.

I dont know why but when you add one more "some" to one of the last two tr's then it looks like this:

[image: example]